# Phalcon: rendering output to variable returns empty string in prod server

Tags: php, phalcon

I have phalcon 3.4.4 installed on windows 01 with php 7.3.7 in my local machine.

i have following code

```
 <?php
    $view = $this->view;
    $view->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
    $view->render("", "testtest");
    $content = $view->getRender('', "testtest", array("name"=>"Mr. XYZ"), function($view)
    {
        $view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
    });
    echo $content;
    exit;
    ?>
```

And Another way to get same output

```
<?php
$this->view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);       
$content = $this->view->getRender('', "testtest", array("name"=>"Mr. XYZ"), function($view)
{
    $view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_LAYOUT);
});    

echo $content;
exit;
?>
```

Both of the above code snippets works perfectly fine in my local machine.

But in production server `$content` returns empty string. No errors displayed and no errors in error logs. The production server is ubuntu with php 7.3.6 with phalcon 3.4.3

Can anybody help me on this what might be wrong, did I miss anything?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a cache problem. Remove the cache

Comment: @AndreiTodorut There doesn't seem to be any cache.

Comment: i would check the views dir and double check for misspells. and if i may ask why would you change the render level twice